# Load Login site instead of the default controller site when no session is set

Tags: codeigniter, redirect

My default controller is home. When no session is set **MY_Controller** is in charge of loading `login_view` instead of home.

Now, this works fine, it indeed does load the `login_view` when no session is set. But it loads it TOGETHER with `home_view`.

In **MY_Controller**, when I set `redirect(site_url('login'));` instead of `$this->load->view('login');` then nothing loads but a browser message:

> :( there is a redirection on this page

MY_Controller:

```
class My_Controller extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        if ($this->session->userdata('username') == '') {
            $this->load->view('login_view');
            //redirect(site_url('login'); --> browser sends error

        }

    }
}
```

I am looking for something like - destroy all other views and load `login_view` when no session is set. Or redirect to `login_view` without receiving a browser redirection `message/error`. Is there something like this? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class My_Controller extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        if ( !$this->session->userdata('username') ) {
            //$this->load->view('login_view');
            redirect('My_Controller/login', 'refresh');
        }
    }

    public function login(){
        #load the view here
        $this->load->view('login_view');
    }
}
```

Comment: ahh inside MY_Controller, I see now. Thank you!